# Laravel backpack restrict user access to admin panel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm trying to change checkIfUserIsAdmin() method in CheckIfAdmin middleware for disabling access to all users without role admin

**What happened**:
Nothing. backpack_user()->can(...) or backpack_user()->role(...) don't working...
Is that right way to restrict user access to admin panel?

bp - 3.5

laravel - 5.7

php - 7.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, create a middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

In this file we will check that the user has ‘admin’ role

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! \Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) 
            return response(trans('backpack::base.unauthorized'),401);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now, add this middleware to /config/backpack/base.php

(don’t delete CheckIfAdmin middleware, just append it)

```
'middleware_class' => [
    \Backpack\Base\app\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
],
```

Offcourse we must cache the config then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but middleware seems not to been executed.

Comment: @Kezern did you cleared config cache after additon middlewae to backpacks config? if dont try php artisan config:cache

Comment: I tried your solution , but it gives this error.
Call to a member function hasRole() on null on \app\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware.php:19

Answer (score 5):

One way is to make a Middleware in Http\Middleware like CheckIfAdmin.php with below function.

```
private function checkIfUserIsAdmin($user)
    {
        return ($user->is_admin == 1);
    }
```

Then add this middleware in array $routeMiddleware of Http\Kernel.php. Like below.

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\checkIfUserIsAdmin::class,
```